# TCPDF only exports .pdf when user is administrator

Tags: user-roles, pdf

## Context

I use TCPDF for PDF generation hooked to `admin-post`. The admin-post-action handling function retrieves an object from database according to query parameters, requires a `template.php` and captures the html output, then writes it to TCPDF and generates a PDF with `$pdf->Output('file.pdf', 'D');`.

On a page I have a basic `<a href=...>` linking to `admin-post.php?action=genPDF&objectIdentifier=xyz`.

This whole thing is accessible only to logged in users with a custom capability, possessed only by `administrator` and custom `client` role .

## Problem

After clicking the link as an `administrator`, a PDF is downloaded. When I click the link as `client`, the page just reloads.

## Attempts to solve

I put some `error_log()` in the PDF-generating function and it does run for the client. I logged the html output captured from template.php and it shows the correct output. When I use Chrome's network inspector, I see the admin-post.php request response headers suggest a PDF file attachment with the correct filename specified in TCPDF Output call. I tried switching the "D" for "I" in output target specification to show PDF in browser instead of downloading it with the same result - administrator gets the PDF, client gets nothing.

## The question

This makes no sense to me. Is there *any* way the WP user role could affect this? The same code is run for administrator and client, up to the point of generating the same HTML output from template and TCPDF setting the response headers.

Answer (score 0):

This was due to 2 mistakes in code restricting client access to wp-admin.

- There was no exception for `admin-post.php` , so after a request to admin-post the client was redirected back to client area. Hence the 'reloads' after clicking the link.
- After the redirect in the restriction code, there was no `die()` or `exit` statement. Therefore the admin-post handler was able to continue running and TCPDF was able to set some HTTP response header info (content type: pdf), but HTTP status 302 was already sent and no file was downloaded. This confused me quite a lot.